# Binary Classification using logistic regression with Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I just too an ML course and am trying to get better at tensorflow. To that end, I purchased the book by Nishant Shukhla (ML with tensorflow) and am trying to run the 2 feature example with a different data set.

With the fake dataset in the book, my code runs fine. However, with data I used in the ML course, the code refuses to converge. With a really small learning rate it does converge, but the learned weights are wrong.
Also attaching the plot of the feature data. It should not a feature scaling issue as values on both features vary between 30-100 units.

### I am really struggling with how opaque tensorflow is- any help would be appreciated:

```
""" Solution for simple logistic regression model
"""
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define paramaters for the model
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 300

data = np.loadtxt('ex2data1.txt', delimiter=',')
x1s = np.array(data[:,0]).astype(np.float32)
x2s = np.array(data[:,1]).astype(np.float32)
ys = np.array(data[:,2]).astype(np.float32)

print('Plotting data with + indicating (y = 1) examples and o \n indicating (y = 0) examples.\n')
color = ['red' if l == 0 else 'blue' for l in ys]
myplot = plt.scatter(x1s, x2s, color = color)

# Put some labels
plt.xlabel("Exam 1 score")
plt.ylabel("Exam 2 score")

# Specified in plot order
plt.show()

# Step 2: Create datasets
X1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,), name="x1")
X2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,), name="x2")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,), name="y")
w = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(3,1), name='w', dtype='float32',trainable=True)
y_model = tf.sigmoid(w[2]*X2 + w[1]*X1 + w[0])
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.log(y_model*Y + (1-y_model)*(1-Y)))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/logreg', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    prev_error = 0.0;
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        error, loss = sess.run([cost, train_op], feed_dict={X1:x1s, X2:x2s, Y:ys})
        print("epoch = ", epoch, "loss = ", loss)
        if abs(prev_error - error) < 0.0001:
            break
        prev_error = error

    w_val = sess.run(w, {X1:x1s, X2:x2s, Y:ys})
    print("w learned = ", w_val)

writer.close()
sess.close()
```

Comment: What do you want us to help you with? Also from `Also attaching the plot of the feature data.`, add plot in the question.

Comment: I guess I was really looking for help with debugging my tensorflow code or figuring out why my algorithm was not converging. Unable to add an image file as I guess I do not have the appropriate credits yet. However, after much tinkering I was able to get the gradient descent to converge. It was a simple matter of scaling the input features. As the min/max ranges of both features were approximately the same I did not think I needed to, but apparently I do.

Answer (score 0):

Both X1 and X2 range from ~20-100. However, once I scaled them, the solution converged just fine.